# pandas to_json , django and d3.js for visualisation

Tags: json, django, pandas, d3.js

I have a pandas dataframe that I converted to json in order to create graphs and visualize with d3.js so I would like to know how to send this json format obtained in django (in the view or template) in order to visualize with d3.js

```
def parasol_view(request):
    parasol = function_parasol()
    parasol_json = parasol.to_json(orient='records')
    parasol = parasol.to_html(index = False, table_id="table_parasol")
    context = {
        'parasol': parasol
        'parasol_json':parasol_json
    }
    return  render(request,'parasol.html',context)
```

template :

```
{%block content%}
    {{parasol| safe}}
    {{parasol_json| safe}}
{%endblock content%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the parasol.to_html is for, therefore I left that part untouched.
But this is what I would do in order to use your .json file:

Views.py:

```
def parasol_view(request):
    parasol = function_parasol()
    # parasol_json = parasol.to_json(orient='records')
    parasol = parasol.to_html(index = False, table_id="table_parasol")
    context = {
        'parasol': parasol
    #   'parasol_json':parasol_json
    }
    return  render(request,'parasol.html', context)
```

Function parasol:

```
function_parasol(){
    #whatever code you have here
    #I made a new var parasol2 for this so that the parasol that will be returned will be the same as before. 
    #So that you can still use it for parasol.to_html
    parasol2 = parasol.to_json(orient='records') 
    
    text_file = open("parasol.json", "w") #name of file, make sure it ends with .json
    text_file.write(parasol2)
    text_file.close()
    
    return parasol
}
```

The javascript file where you want to make a graph with d3:

```
//so basically var_name = parasol.json
d3.json("/parasol.json", function(var_name) {
    //Go make your graphs
});
```

Ps. If you were to upload the file that gets parsed into a json file. Parasol.json will be overwritten every time.
So there won't be an abundance of json files at some point.